# Implementing GraphQL in .NET Core 2.0 WebApi

Tags: c#, postgresql, asp.net-web-api, graphql, asp.net-core-2.0

I was wondering if you could help me out with GraphQL and .NET Asp.Net WebAPI  please.

I currently have this scenario where I have a .NET Core 2.0 WebApi project and uses Postgresql as a database backend. (See implementation below).

*Client Implementation:*

```
public class Client {
   public long Id { get; set; }
   public Name Name { get; set; }
   public long Id { get; set; }
   public string Email { get; set; }
   public IEnumerable<Paper> Papers { get; set;}
}

public class Name {
   public string First {get; set;}
   public string Middle {get; set;}
   public string Last {get; set;}
}

public class Paper {
   public long Id { get; set; }
   public string Content { get; set; }
   public string Title { get; set; }
}

public class ClientService
{
    public IMyRepository _clients;

    public ClientService(IMyRepository client) {
        _clients = client;
    }

    public IEnumerable<Client> GetClients()
    {
        return _clients.GetAllClients();
    }

    public IEnumerable<Client> Search(long id) {
        return _clients.GetById(id);
    }

    public IEnumerable<Client> SearchByEmail(string email) {
        return _clients.GetById(id);
    }

    public IEnumerable<Client> SearchPapers(string title) {
        return _clients.GetClientsWithPaperTitle(title);
    }

    // and any other searches I want to implement based on Client and Paper classes
}


public class ClientController: Controller
{
    private ClientService _service;

    public ClientController(ClientService service) {
        _service = service;
    }

    public IActionResult Get() {
        var records = _service.GetClients();
        return new JsonResult(records);
    }

    // This is where I'm getting stuck
    public IActionResult Search(string value) {
        var records = _service.GetClients();
        return new JsonResult(records);
    }
}

public class Query {
    private ClientService _service;

    [GraphQLMetadata("client")]
    public async Task<IClient> GetClient()
    {
        return _service.GetClients();
    }

    [GraphQLMetadata("client")]
    public async Task<IClient> GetClient(string email, long id, long paperId, string paperTitle)
    {
        return _service.GetClients();
    }


}
```

I am thinking of providing a single endpoint where I want the webapi client consumer to provide the filters one needs based on a predefined, expected class object.

Given that GraphQL has the ability to expose a query-like function, do GraphQL have the ability to do complex WHERE clauses where I could pass a filter object similar to this?

If using the query GetClient(email: "test@email.com")

```
 {
        client(email: "test@email.com, paper: "MyPaperTitle", range.paperId (1,5) {
            Id
            Name
            Email
            Papers {
                Title
                Content
            }
        }
   }
```

Which is an equivalent Postgresql query of

```
SELECT *
   FROM 
        client
        inner join papers on client.Id = Papers.ClientId
    WHERE
        Email = 'test@email.com'
        and papers.title LIKE 'MyTitle%'
        and papers.id  between 1 and 5
    ;
```

Or:

```
 {
        client(email: "test@email.com) {
            Id
            Name
            Email
            Papers (paper: "MyPaperTitle") {
                Title
                Content
            }
        }
   }
```

Which is an equivalent Postgresql query of

```
SELECT *
   FROM 
        client
        inner join papers on client.Id = Papers.ClientId
    WHERE
        Email = 'test@email.com'
        and papers.title LIKE 'MyTitle%'
    ;
```

Would really appreciate any help/advice on this.

Many thanks,
Ann

Comment: Here's an in-depth guide on using graphql-dotnet with ASP.NET Core 2.0, Entity Framework Core and Sql Server.  If you're still working on this it may be of some use.  https://fullstackmark.com/post/17/building-a-graphql-api-with-aspnet-core-2-and-entity-framework-core

Comment: Thanks for this! @mmacneil007